# reaching properties from hasChanged

Tags: javascript, lit-element

i am trying to call a function from lit element hasChanged method,but it gives undefined

```
static get properties() {
    let dis=this;
    return {
        projeid:{type:Number}, 

        _arr:{type:Array},
        _input_obj: {type: Object},
        _funksiyalar:{type:Object},
        input_objectler_array:
        {
            type:Array,
            hasChanged:function(newVal,oldVal){

                console.log(dis._funksiyalar);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}

constructor() {
    super();

    this._arr = ["No:", "Aciqlama", "Vahid", "Miqdar", "Vahidin Qiymeti", "Toplam"];
    this._input_obj=this._arr.reduce((o, key) => Object.assign(o, {[key]: ""},{detaylar:[]}), {});
    this.input_objectler_array=[];

    this._funksiyalar={
        Objectler_Array_hasChanged(newVal) {
            let event = new CustomEvent("array-updated", {
                detail: {
                    array: newVal
                }
            });
            this.dispatchEvent(event);
        }
    };


}
```

how could i reach a property or method from lit-element hasChanged method?

Comment: If you don't use TypeScript, you can declare property values at the `constructor.` in JS. See more detail : https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/properties#declare-properties-in-a-static-properties-getter

Answer (score 1):

`hasChanged` is called *immediately* and synchronously on set, so in your `constructor`:

```js
this.input_objectler_array=[];
// hasChanged fires, this._funksiyalar is undefined

this._funksiyalar={...
```

You should be able to work around this just by defining `_funksiyalar` *first*;

```js
this._funksiyalar={...
this.input_objectler_array=[];
// hasChanged fires, this._funksiyalar is now set
```

Lit uses a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) to create property set methods, so it's as if you had something like:

```
_internalVal;

set input_objectler_array(v) {
    const hasChanged = function(newVal,oldVal){
        console.log(dis._funksiyalar);
        return true;
    };

    if(hasChanged(v, this._internalVal)) {
        this._internalVal = v;
        this.requestUpdate(); // this queues up the change to render
    }
}
```

List uses `hasChanged` to determine whether it needs to change the value, so it's a bad idea to hook side effects like events to it. You might do this if you wanted the event to be cancellable or able to change the value, but I'd recommend either your own custom `set` method or moving that logic outside of the render control entirely (maybe with a [`ReactiveController`](https://lit.dev/docs/composition/controllers/)) if you want to do that.

Instead override [`updated`](https://lit.dev/docs/components/lifecycle/#reactive-update-cycle-completing) to fire events *after* a value changes:

```js
updated(changedProperties) {
    if (changedProperties.has('input_objectler_array')) {
        const event = new CustomEvent('array-updated', {
            detail: {
                // component has updated, changedProperties holds the old value
                array: this.input_objectler_array; 
            }
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Now this `updated` fires *asynchronously*, once the update has happened, so your `array-updated` event will fire once the component is connected and rendered in the page rather than in the constructor. This will allow programmatic creation to work:

```js
const ele = document.createElement('my-element'); // constructor event fires here
ele.addEventListener('array-updated', doSomething);
containerElement.append(ele); // updated event fires after this
```

Comment: Thank you! This saved me from a long evening of banging my head on the keyboard.